# Ruby on Rails: How to prevent confirmation emails when migrating users in database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, actionmailer

In our app, we would like to migrate users from old table to a new one, managed by devise gem. I linked the two tables with an attribute `old_id` so I can always go back to the previous user information and get other data from there. Here is the migration script (once tables are created):

```
class PopulateV3idInUsersTable < ActiveRecord::Migration

  def up
    User.all.each do |u|
      old_u = OldUser.find_by( email: u.email )
      unless old_u.nil?
        u.old_id = old_u.id
        u.skip_confirmation!
        u.save
      end
    end
  end

end
```

The database is correctly updated. The problem is that, each time we update a user with his old id, the script sends a confirmation email to the user, which is really not good...

In the previous code, I added `u.skip_confirmation!` but it still doesn't work. I also tried other possibilities like `u.confirm!` and `u.confirmation_token = nil ; u.confirmed_at = Time.now` but they all failed.

Do you have an idea? Thanks.

Comment: cant you skip active record callbacks by using `update_all` http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/update_all/class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
class PopulateV3idInUsersTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    User.all.each do |u|
      old_u = OldUser.find_by( email: u.email )
      unless old_u.nil?
        u.old_id = old_u.id
        u.skip_confirmation_notification!
        u.confirmation_sent_at = nil
        u.save
      end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

As Luke mentioned, you want to use `#skip_confirmation_notification!` rather than `#skip_confirmation!`.

But this will only do the trick in your migration task. Next time an update occurs on the user (say, he wants to change his first name), the confirmation mail will be sent again.

If devise tries to send a confirmation email, that's because :

1. your User model includes `:confirmable` and
2. your users has no `confirmed_at` attribute set

### not using confirmable

If you don't want confirmation at all, remove `:confirmable` from devise options :

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # whatever modules you want to use, except :confirmable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registrable, :recoverable
end
```

### using confirmable

If you want to use confirmable but fix your old users problem, set their `#confirmed_at` attribute in your migration :

```
class PopulateV3idInUsersTable < ActiveRecord::Migration

  def up
    User.all.each do |u|
      old_u = OldUser.find_by( email: u.email )

      u.confirmed_at = Time.now    
      u.old_id = old_u.id unless old_u.nil?
      u.save
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Olivier for your deep answer. I now understand more what's happening. What is strange, is that sometimes I use `u.confirm!` and it is enough to not send email (especially in controllers) but not in migration!! Thanks anyway.

Comment: Well, `#confirm!` is precisely [about setting #confirmed_at](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/confirmable.rb#L56) ;)

Comment: Great answer @OlivierElMekki.  I think you deserve the +15 ;)

Comment: Np, the answers are there, it's all that matters :)